# I can't get gtkmm to compile on Mac using CMake

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, gtkmm

I'm attempting to set up an environment in which I can use gtkmm for C++ development. My CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(program)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3.0)

link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(include ${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")

add_executable(program ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(program ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})
```

Yet when I try to include the line `include <gtkmm.h>` in main I am met with this error from CMake:

```
fatal error: 'gtkmm.h' file not found
#include <gtkmm.h>
```

I installed gtkmm with brew using the command `brew install gtkmm` and `brew install gtkmm3` to insure versions were not the issue. What can I do to get this working?

Comment: What is the value of `${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS}`? You can do `message(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})`.

Comment: @squareskittles Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

Comment: You should first address any errors you have from running CMake *before* attempting compilation. Is `pkg-config` even installed on your system? What happens when you type `which pkg-config`?

Comment: @Laif: Please, add configuration messages (like `Could NOT find PkgConfig`) into your question post. It is weird that the question post doesn't contain the key messages which affects on resolving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to install pkg-config (using brew).

Here is a CMakeLists.txt file that will work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(program LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3.0)

add_executable(program)

target_compile_features(program PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

target_sources(program PRIVATE main.cpp)

target_include_directories(program PRIVATE ${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_directories(program PRIVATE ${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(program PRIVATE ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})
```